# twitter-like auto refresh feature using MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, twitter, refresh

How can i create the twitter auto-refresh effect in an MVC 2 Application ?

thanks

Comment: for those unfamilliar, can you briefly describe the twitter auto-refresh effect?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) javascript function which allows you to execute some code at regular intervals. Then you could send an AJAX request to the server to see if there are updates and refresh some portion of the page. Here's an example of how you could poll a server action for updates:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this will execute every 5 seconds
    // send an AJAX request
    $.get('/someaction', { }, function(result) {
        // use the result returned from the server
        // to update the DOM
    });
}, 5000);
```